# MAMP fails to update mysql

Tags: mamp

When I try to start my mysql and apache servers through MAMP on macOS, I get a message every time saying that mysql needs to be updated.

I try to update mysql through the MAMP interface, but it errors out with this:

```
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
Looking for 'mysql' as: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql
Looking for 'mysqlcheck' as: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqlcheck
Error: Failed while fetching Server version! Could be due to unauthorized access.
FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed
```

I found a very similar thread, that suggested trying /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql_upgrade --port=3306 -u root -p in the terminal. When I try that I get this error output:

```
Looking for 'mysql' as: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql
Looking for 'mysqlcheck' as: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqlcheck
Running 'mysqlcheck' with connection arguments: '--port=3306'
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
Running 'mysqlcheck' with connection arguments: '--port=3306'
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
mysql.columns_priv                                 OK
mysql.db                                           OK
mysql.event                                        OK
mysql.func                                         OK
mysql.general_log                                  OK
mysql.help_category                                OK
mysql.help_keyword                                 OK
mysql.help_relation                                OK
mysql.help_topic                                   OK
mysql.innodb_index_stats
Error    : Table 'mysql.innodb_index_stats' doesn't exist
status   : Operation failed
mysql.innodb_table_stats
Error    : Table 'mysql.innodb_table_stats' doesn't exist
status   : Operation failed
mysql.ndb_binlog_index                             OK
mysql.plugin                                       OK
mysql.proc                                         OK
mysql.procs_priv                                   OK
mysql.proxies_priv                                 OK
mysql.servers                                      OK
mysql.slave_master_info
Error    : Table 'mysql.slave_master_info' doesn't exist
status   : Operation failed
mysql.slave_relay_log_info
Error    : Table 'mysql.slave_relay_log_info' doesn't exist
status   : Operation failed
mysql.slave_worker_info
Error    : Table 'mysql.slave_worker_info' doesn't exist
status   : Operation failed
mysql.slow_log                                     OK
mysql.tables_priv                                  OK
mysql.time_zone                                    OK
mysql.time_zone_leap_second                        OK
mysql.time_zone_name                               OK
mysql.time_zone_transition                         OK
mysql.time_zone_transition_type                    OK
mysql.user                                         OK

Repairing tables
mysql.innodb_index_stats
Error    : Table 'mysql.innodb_index_stats' doesn't exist
status   : Operation failed
mysql.innodb_table_stats
Error    : Table 'mysql.innodb_table_stats' doesn't exist
status   : Operation failed
mysql.slave_master_info
Error    : Table 'mysql.slave_master_info' doesn't exist
status   : Operation failed
mysql.slave_relay_log_info
Error    : Table 'mysql.slave_relay_log_info' doesn't exist
status   : Operation failed
mysql.slave_worker_info
Error    : Table 'mysql.slave_worker_info' doesn't exist
status   : Operation failed
Running 'mysql_fix_privilege_tables'...
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 62: Table 'mysql.innodb_table_stats' doesn't exist
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 63: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to EXECUTE
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 64: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to DEALLOCATE PREPARE
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 66: Table 'mysql.innodb_index_stats' doesn't exist
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 67: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to EXECUTE
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 68: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to DEALLOCATE PREPARE
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 81: Table 'mysql.slave_relay_log_info' doesn't exist
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 82: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to EXECUTE
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 83: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to DEALLOCATE PREPARE
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 110: Table 'mysql.slave_master_info' doesn't exist
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 111: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to EXECUTE
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 112: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to DEALLOCATE PREPARE
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 128: Table 'mysql.slave_worker_info' doesn't exist
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 129: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to EXECUTE
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 130: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to DEALLOCATE PREPARE
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 1896: Table 'mysql.slave_master_info' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 1897: Table 'mysql.slave_master_info' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 1898: Table 'mysql.slave_master_info' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 1899: Table 'mysql.slave_worker_info' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 1900: Table 'mysql.slave_relay_log_info' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 1904: Table 'mysql.innodb_table_stats' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 1908: Table 'mysql.innodb_index_stats' doesn't exist
FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed
```

I also tried finding the my.cnf file for MAMP and backing it up as someone else in that other thread I mentioned suggested but could not find it. If someone would not mind pointing out to me where it is, so that I can see if updating mysql after that works.

I will also add that I am using MAMP version 4.2 on macOS 10.12. If that helps any.

Comment: have you found the solution? I came into same problem.. :/

Comment: Sorry to hear you are having the same issue. Unfortunately, I never ended up finding a solution.